# how to remove dirty data in yugabyte ( postgresql )

Tags: database, postgresql, yugabytedb

I try to add a column to a table with GUI Tableplus, but no response for long time.
So I turn to the db server, but got these error:
[image]

Maybe some inconsistent data generated during the operation through the Tableplus.

I am new to postgresql , and don't know what to do next.

-----updated------

I did some operation as @Dri372 told, and got some progress.
[image]
The failed reason for table sys_role and s2 is that the tables are not empty, they have some records.
If I run sql like this `create table s3 AS SELECT * FROM sys_role; alter table s3 add column project_code varchar(50);`, I successed.

Now how could I still work on the table sys_role?

Comment: First show the result of : \d sys_role

Comment: Then try create table s2 AS SELECT * FROM sys_role; and try your cde on this 2nd table

Comment: @Dri372 I attached screenshots in the original question, and update some information .
Thank for you suggestion let me know where I did wrong before.

Comment: No idea fro the cause till now. 2 more tests to do. 1) in this dn, create table s3 (...); ... 2) create a new db without TablePlus and do the same tests.

Comment: What version are you using (select version();) ?

Comment: @dorianYB
PostgreSQL 11.2-YB-2.3.3.0-b0 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Homebrew gcc 5.5.0_4) 5.5.0, 64-bit

Comment: yugabyte is quite different from Postgres

Comment: See reply here: https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/8952#issuecomment-863162912